# Stata: Aggregating by week

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that has a date variable with missing dates.

```
var1
15sep2014
15sep2014
17sep2014
18sep2014
22sep2014
22sep2014
22sep2014
29sep2014
06oct2014
```

I aggregated the data using this command.

```
gen week = week(var1)
```

and the results look like this

```
var 1      week
15sep2014   37
15sep2014   37
17sep2014   38
18sep2014   38
22sep2014   38
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to get the month name and year in the week variable.

Comment: Orthogonal to your question, but I'd call this a dataset with omitted dates or with gaps; "missing dates" at first reading perhaps implies dates with values that are missing. That is, you have observations on which date variables have missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `week()` is part of the solution if and only if you define your weeks according to Stata's rules for weeks. They are

1. Week 1 of the year starts on January 1, regardless.
2. Week 2 of the year starts on January 8, regardless.
3. And so on, except that week 52 of the year includes 8 or 9 days, depending on 
   whether the year is leap or not.

Do you use these rules? I guess not. Then the simplest practice is to define a week by whichever day starts the week. If your weeks start on Sundays, then use the rule `(`dailydate `- dow(`dailydate`))`. If your weeks start on Mondays, ..., Saturdays, adjust the definition.

```
. clear 

. input str9 svar1

     svar1
1. "15sep2014"
2. "15sep2014"
3. "17sep2014"
4. "18sep2014"
5. "22sep2014"
6. "22sep2014"
7. "22sep2014"
8. "29sep2014"
9. "06oct2014" 
10. end 

. gen var1 = daily(svar1, "DMY") 

. gen week = var1 - dow(var1) 

. format week var1 %td 

. list

    +-----------------------------------+
    |     svar1        var1        week |
    |-----------------------------------|
 1. | 15sep2014   15sep2014   14sep2014 |
 2. | 15sep2014   15sep2014   14sep2014 |
 3. | 17sep2014   17sep2014   14sep2014 |
 4. | 18sep2014   18sep2014   14sep2014 |
 5. | 22sep2014   22sep2014   21sep2014 |
    |-----------------------------------|
 6. | 22sep2014   22sep2014   21sep2014 |
 7. | 22sep2014   22sep2014   21sep2014 |
 8. | 29sep2014   29sep2014   28sep2014 |
 9. | 06oct2014   06oct2014   05oct2014 |
    +-----------------------------------+
```

Much more discussion [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0052), [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0065) and [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0065_1), although the first should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `week()` function, I would probably use the `wofd()` function to transform your `%td` daily date into a `%tw` weekly date. Then you can just play with the datetime display formats to decide exactly how to format the date. For example:

```
gen date_weekly = wofd(var1)
format date_weekly %twww:_Mon_ccYY
```

That code should give you this:

```
var1        date_weekly
15sep2014   37: Sep 2014
15sep2014   37: Sep 2014
17sep2014   38: Sep 2014
18sep2014   38: Sep 2014
22sep2014   38: Sep 2014
```

This help file will be useful:

```
help datetime display formats
```

And if you want to brush up on the difference between `%tw` and `%td` dates, you might refresh yourself here:

```
help datetime
```

Comment: That doesn't address the idiosyncratic definition of weeks in Stata, which is unlikely to correspond to substantive needs. Please see my answer and its references.